# Foursquare: what kind of HTTP error code will be returned in case of rate_limit_exceeded?

Tags: api, http, foursquare

The https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/responses page shows the range of http errors that can be returned by foursquare api, along with the error types.

What that document is missing, is the association response <--> error types.

For example, what kind of http error will  be associated with rate_limit_exceeded? 403?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! We'll return a 403 in this case.

I've made a note for us to update the documentation with this information.